# Angular.js: update binding after manual modification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm only starting to dive into angular.js and have found this issue that I can't seem to get around. Consider this simple code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test">
<input type="text" value="{{test}}">
```

When I write in the first field, the second one is updated nicely. When I write in the second field and then go back to the first one, the binding is not updated anymore. Interestingly though, the HTML attribute `value` **does** get updated - it's just not displayed.

Equivalent (at least roughly) code in vanilla javascript does not suffer from this:

```
<input type="text" id="model">
<input type="text" id="binding">
<script>
    var model = document.getElementById("model");
    var binding = document.getElementById("binding");
    model.addEventListener("keyup",function() {
        binding.value = model.value;
    });
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle for you to test both: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6b5k/

Any idea why this happens when using angular.js and how to fix this?

[EDIT] Judging by the initial replies, it appears I have not made it clear. I do not want the second field to update the first one. The binding is to be one-way only, e.g. to allow filtering or even manual corrections (such as automatic creation of a URL alias in a blog post creation form). http://jsfiddle.net/Q6b5k/1/

Comment: why would you want to use `value="{{test}}"` instead of `ng-model="test"`

Comment: Because I want to filter the value: `{{test|lowercase}}`

Comment: whether you want the second textbox to editable and changes copied to textbox 1

Comment: won't it cause the case to be changed in the original field

Comment: Please see my edit. The second field should have no influence over the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value attribute is only used when rendering the initial HTML.  After the page load, everything else happens in the [Angular Event Loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) and therefore you need to do something that event loop can pick up.  You can use [ng-change](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) for what you are looking to do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="test2=test.toLowerCase();" />
<input type="text" ng-model="test2"">
```

Comment: Hey, this seems to get me closer to what I want to achieve! Do you know whether it's possible to use filters defined in my app?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `{{value}}` does not create a binding, it is used for interpolation.

The simplest solution is to use ng-model in both the fields

```
<div ng-app>
    Angular.js:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test">
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WwKxZ/)

Comment: The thing is, I want to filter the bound value afterwards, effectively displaying a different string than in the model field.